# How to draw a small dot on every click of the mouse in a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I have a `WinForms` program where the user clicks on a `PictureBox` control.
I want a small red dot (a few pixels across) every time the user clicks.
I also don't want any of the previous dots to go away.

I know I will need a generic list of ellipses and rectangles, but am not sure how to execute this. How would I go about doing this?

In my program a `pictureBox1_Click` method handles mouse click events and returns the position of the clicks.
A `pictureBox1_Paint` method handles the graphics to be drawn on these points.

Comment: PictureBox has a Paint event.  It already knows how to draw its Image property by itself, you can add whatever you need on top of it.  The only thing you have to do is tell it to redraw and fire its Paint event again, us its Invalidate() method.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant , as of now I am creating rectangle objects in the Click method, do I just pass the array of objects to the Paint method?

Comment: You need to store the list of data to draw at e.g. class level, maybe a List<Rectangle> or a List<Point> etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a container that can reference the Points collection and add one point to the collection each time you click on a paint-able Control.

Maybe, you want to also create different kinds of drawing *points*, based on some conditions or requirements.
Thus, you need to store also these extra properties, not just a point coordinate.
If so, you need a specialized object that can expose these properties when needed.

So, here's a custom `Class` object with some simple properties, that lets you define a Point's Color and Size. For each of its Points collection.
It also implements the **`IDisposable`** interface, because we need to create a **`Pen`** object for each Point we draw. And a **`Pen`** object needs to be disposed (implements **`IDisposable`**).

To perform the drawing, you just need to call **`Control.Invalidate()`** (`pictureBox1.Invalidate()` in the example). This causes the repainting of the invalidated parts of the control, raising the **`OnPaint()`** event.
Each point (that needs to be repainted) is drawn using **`e.Graphics.DrawEllipse()`**.

You can test it this way:

**With predefined properties, using just a Mouse pointer coordinate:**

**`myPoints.Add(new MyPoints.DrawingPoint(e.Location));`**

**With specific properties when something different is needed:**

With a size of 8x8 pixels
**`newPoint.Dot = new Rectangle(e.Location, new Size(8, 8)));`**.

With an orange Pen of 2 pixels in size
**`newPoint.DrawingPen = new Pen(Color.Orange, 2);`**

Add this new Point to the collection
**`myPoints.DrawingPoints.Add(newPoint);`**

The `Clear()` method is used to `Dispose()` the current list of Points and create a new, empty, List:
**`MyPoints.Clear();`**

**Sample implementation**:

```
MyPoints myPoints = new MyPoints();

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Use default property values
    //myPoints.Add(new MyPoints.DrawingPoint(e.Location));

    MyPoints.DrawingPoint newPoint = new MyPoints.DrawingPoint();
    newPoint.Dot = new Rectangle(e.Location, new Size(4, 4));
    newPoint.DrawingPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
    myPoints.DrawingPoints.Add(newPoint);
    (sender as Control).Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (MyPoints.DrawingPoint mypoint in myPoints.DrawingPoints) {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(mypoint.DrawingPen, mypoint.Dot);
    }
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    myPoints.Dispose();
}
```

**The Point objects collection Class container**:

```
internal class MyPoints : IDisposable
{
    bool IsDisposed = false;
    public MyPoints() => DrawingPoints = new List<DrawingPoint>();

    public List<DrawingPoint> DrawingPoints { get; set; }
    public void Add(DrawingPoint NewPoint)
    {
        if (NewPoint.Dot.Size.Width > 1 && NewPoint.Dot.Size.Height > 1) {
            DrawingPoints.Add(NewPoint);
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this.Dispose();
        this.DrawingPoints.Clear();
        this.DrawingPoints = new List<DrawingPoint>();
    }

    public void Remove(Point point)
    {
        Remove(this.DrawingPoints.Select((p, i) => { if (p.Dot.Contains(point)) return i; return -1; }).First());
    }

    public void Remove(int Index)
    {
        if (Index > -1) {
            this.DrawingPoints[Index].Delete();
            this.DrawingPoints.RemoveAt(Index);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected void Dispose(bool IsSafeDisposing)
    {
        if (IsSafeDisposing && (!this.IsDisposed) && (this.DrawingPoints.Count > 0)) {
            foreach (DrawingPoint dp in this.DrawingPoints)
                if (dp != null) dp.Delete();
        }
    }

    public class DrawingPoint
    {
        Pen m_Pen = null;
        Rectangle m_Dot = Rectangle.Empty;

        public DrawingPoint() : this(Point.Empty) { }
        public DrawingPoint(Point newPoint)
        {
            this.m_Pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
            this.m_Dot = new Rectangle(newPoint, new Size(2, 2));
        }

        public Pen DrawingPen { get => this.m_Pen; set => this.m_Pen = value; }
        public Rectangle Dot { get => this.m_Dot; set => this.m_Dot = value; }
        public void Delete()
        {
            if (this.m_Pen != null) this.m_Pen.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how it can work, changing its properties when required:

[image: DottedColors1]

Comment: Drawing the points works like a charm. I'm just having issues when I change the image in picturebox. I snuck in a myPoints.Dispose() into the method where i change the picture. It also breaks when I call a method to Dispose myPoints during runtime

Comment: @Eric Lopez-Reyes  Well, the `Dispose()` method implemented is meant to be called when you need to destroy your collection of points (when a `Form` is closed), to avoid leaking GDI resources (the `Pen` object). Or when you remove 1 element. You would need a `.Clear()` method, as used in a `List<>` object, to empty the list. I didn't implement that (lack of time), but I agree it should be there. I'll modify the class to include a method that clears the list, so, when you change a Picture, you don't carry around the old Points (you could also dispose the Object and create a new one).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll see if I could do anything to fix it in the meantime

Comment: @Eric Lopez-Reyes  I added a Clear() method to the Main class (`MyPoints.Clear()`). This will dispose the list of Points and create a new one. You can then add a new `PictureBox.Image` and restart with just: `MyPoint.Clear(); pictureBox1.Image = [New Image];` and start drawing from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you must use GDI+

Check the code bellow:

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);

        var cursorPosition = pictureBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        g.DrawEllipse(p, cursorPosition.X, cursorPosition.Y, 15, 15);

        MyCircles.Add(cursorPosition);
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }


    List<Point> MyCircles = new List<Point>();

    private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in MyCircles)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"One circle was created: X:{item.X}, Y:{item.Y}");
        }
    }
```

The MyCircles List is only if you want to store the circles to reshow the image with the circles later, and the doubleclick is a sample of using it (i mean persistency purposes, because the circles will not leave the image until you close your app). Check other **g** methods to draw lines, rectangles or whatever. (Uses System.Drawing namespace)

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a simple solution for my problem
I made a list of rectangles:

```
        List<Rectangle> rects = new List<Rectangle>();
```

And added rectangles with ever click:

```
        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
             rects.Add(new Rectangle(e.Location, new Size(4,4)));
        }
```

And painted the points:

```
        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var rect in rects)
        {

            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(magenta,rect);
        }
    }
```

And added a method for clearing drawings with rects.Clear()